# How to change display normalization settings in CImg?

Tags: c++, cimg

I have read this part of the [CImg documentation](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/reference/group__cimg__displays.html):

However, it is not clear how to set this normalization levels (it is not a display() function parameter).

Can anybody tell me how to use them? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two methods :

- The clean one : you specify the `normalization` parameter at the construction of the `CImgDisplay` instance, like :

  `CImgDisplay disp(img,"Title",normalization_type);`

or
    `CImgDisplay disp(640,480,"Title",normalization_type);`

- The dirty one : you can also change the normalization type of an existing display directly by setting it like this :

  `disp._normalization = normalization_type;`

Comment: But I am using a CImg<T> class, something like this: CImg<Int> img (256,256, 1,3,0) /*...*/ img.display("Title");

Should I change and create a CImgDisplay?

Comment: Ha. In this case, the `normalization` parameter used by the underlying CImgDisplay depends on the pixel type your displayed image has. Basically, the normalization will be done for `CImg<float>`and `CImg<double>`, whereas no normalization will occur for usual integer types. To force the normalization, I would suggest to first create a display `CImgDisplay disp(img,"Title",normalization);`then use it like this `img.display(disp,true);`